# NoMethodError in PagesController#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, nomethoderror

I'm working through the Rails Tutorial Chapter 12, and get the following error on the Home/Main page when user is signed out (signed in is OK):

I'm a newbie to Rails so please be explicit in your response! Many thanks..

**NoMethodError in PagesController#home**

```
undefined method `feed' for nil:NilClass
```

Rails.root: /Users/fkhalid2008/Documents/First-app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:6:in `home'
```

**Pages Controller**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def home
  @title = "Home"
  @post = Post.new if signed_in?
  @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end

def contact
  @title = "Contact"
end

def about
  @title = "About Us"
end

end
```

**Home Page View (/app/views/pages/home.html.erb)**

```
<% if signed_in? %>
<table class="front" summary="For signed-in users">
<tr>
  <td class="main">
    <h1 class="post">What's up?</h1>
    <%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
    <%= render 'shared/feed' %>
  </td>
  <td class="sidebar round">
    <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<% else %>
<h1>Palazzo Valencia</h1>

<p>
This is the home page for the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Palazzo Valencia</a>
sample application.
</p>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, :class => "signup_button round" %>
<% end %>
```

**Feed Partial**

```
<% unless @feed_items.empty? %>
<table class="posts" summary="User posts">
<%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

**Feed_item Partial**

```
<tr>
<td class="gravatar">
<%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
</td>
<td class="post">
<span class="user">
  <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
</span>
<span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
<span class="timestamp">
  Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
</span>
</td>
<% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
<td>
<%= link_to "delete", feed_item, :method => :delete,
                                 :confirm => "You sure?",
                                 :title => feed_item.content %>
</td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

The user is not signed in. Therefore, the `current_user` method is returning nil, and ruby can't find the `feed` method.

You could change the code to this:

```
@title = "Home"
if signed_in?
    @post = Post.new
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Now, the new post and the feed items will only be retrieved when the user is signed in.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help :) Don't forget to mark this as an answer. It's appreciated by the Stackoverflow users, and will help you get good help here with future questions that you might have.

Comment: noted, and thank you for the tip. I see your answer has already been marked in this case, but will take care of this in the future (as you can tell, i'm a newbie on SE)

Answer (score 0):

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
  def home
    if logged_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```